# How can I create a "copy on change" copy of a folder in linux?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, file-transfer

I have a set of tools for building a very large project. At several high level stages my tools  create copies of the build environment (a directory) to allow the user to roll back to that point.

I am trying to speed up this copy operation (space is not a big issue, but time is) so I would like to find a way to create a copy of the build directory that consists entirely of links (soft or hard or similar) to the original files but that will never modify the original files, but rather automatically create copies of them when they are being (or might be) changed.

Note: these tools are for doing a build, so the collateral files will have a short lifetime, they will not need to be preserved for a long time and can always be recreated form original code at the cost of time, so I have not been considering SCM solutions like Subversion.

Comment: I'ver never used snapshots myself, but a filesystem supporting _snapshots_ might be the solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_snapshot#FS

Comment: It looks like a convoluted way to have version control. Why not using a VCS instead? (eg GIT)

Comment: As I mentioned the lifetime of the data isn't very long (days or weeks), also because this is a build environment some of the folders actually come from other SCMs (git/svn) so checking the whole thing into an SCM would be begging for conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

A SCM *can* be used for this:

1. Create a repository with just a single commit:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "initial commit"
   ```
2. Build
3. Revert to original state

   ```
   git checkout -f   # discard modifications to committed files
   git clean -f -d   # delete files that were not committed
   ```

To achieve real copy-on-write, you will need filesystem-level support. `zfs` allows creating per-filesystem snapshots (and it's cheap to create a separate zfs filesystem just for the build root); in `btrfs`, the same is done through subvolumes. Also, in btrfs, you have a new link type called "reflinks", which are like hardlinks but with CoW.

```
btrfs subvolume create ~/build.base
[fill ~/build.base]
btrfs subvolume snapshot ~/build.base ~/build.temp
[run build in ~/build.temp]
btrfs subvolume delete ~/build.temp
```